# Break Loop on pressing =

Tags: c#

How can i break the loop when = is pressed instead of 0  without advanced code please because i'm still at the start

[Here's the code][1]

```
  internal class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int sum = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a number (or 0 to exit): ");
                string input = (Console.ReadLine());

                if (input == "=")
                {
                    break;
                }

                sum += Convert.ToInt32(input);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"The sum of all the numbers is: {sum}");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of getting an `int` get a `string` from `Console.ReadLine()` like this:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

then check if it is `=` and break:

```
if(input == "=")
{
    break;
}
```

and you can still use it as a number in the cases that they didn't input `=`, full code would be something like

```
int sum = 0;

while(true)
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number (or = to exit)");
    string input = Console.ReadLine(); // Take input as string
    
    if(input == "=") // If they entered =, break
    {
        break;
    }

    sum += Convert.ToInt32(input); // If they entered a number, convert it to integer
}

Console.WriteLine($"The sum of all the numbers is: {sum}");
```